# How is 3D plane normal vector related to its rotation

Tags: geometry

What i am trying to do http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CaTI2d0tQME 3:15

In my 3D api there is quad.rotation[x,y,z], quad[x,y,z] which is center of it and width/height. I understand that vertices are being calculated from all of the given. And normal can be calculated from vertices but i have a feeling i should be able to get it just from the rotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can !

Your quad must be axis-oriented (along the X, Y or Z axis, which is its normal vector in its local space). Compose this vector with the quad rotation matrix and you will have your new, nice and shiny normal vector in world space !

A little warning : if the quad transformation matrix is generated by any 3D engine, it could contain scaling factors that will mess the normal vector up. In this case, the classical solution is to compute the transposed inverse of the matrix, or to generate your custom transformation matrix with the quad's rotation values.

Comment: A rotation matrix can be represented by 3x3 values as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).
You only have to [multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) the normal vector with this matrix and you're done.